# How to detect if the game object is left or right from the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, position

The Debug.Log always returns LEFT while it needs to be only right when it's on the right side of the player.
Now it's showing both left and right (when on the right side of the game object).

```cs
if (distance <= 249)
        {
            if (enemy.transform.position.x > player.transform.position.x)
            {
                if (waitTime == 0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("LEFT");
                    FireGunsLeft();
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (waitTime == 0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("RIGHT");
                    FireGunsRight();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is this a 2d or 3d game?

Comment: @Ruzihm It's a 3D game

Comment: @RetiredNinja how/why should this help?

Answer (score 3):

#### Use `player.transform.InverseTransformPoint(enemy.transform.position)`

You can use [`Transform.InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) to find the enemy's relative position from the perspective of the player.

```
Vector3 enemyDirectionLocal = player.transform.InverseTransformPoint(enemy.transform.position);
```

This `Vector3 enemyDirectionLocal` is a vector that describes the enemy's position offset 
 from the player's position along the player's left/right, up/down, and forward/back axes.

What this means is that if `enemyDirectionLocal.x` is less than zero, it's on the left side of the player (although maybe ahead or behind as well), and if it's greater than zero, it's on the right side.  If it's zero, it's directly behind or ahead of the player.

```
Vector3 enemyDirectionLocal = player.transform.InverseTransformPoint(enemy.transform.position);

if (enemyDirectionLocal.x < 0)
{
    if (waitTime == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("LEFT");
        FireGunsLeft();
    }
}
else if (enemyDirectionLocal.x > 0)
{
    if (waitTime == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("RIGHT");
        FireGunsRight();
    }
}
```

Comment: personally I would also flip the if checks and do `if(waitTime == 0)` only once ;) What happens if the positons are the same (unlikely but possible)?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to find the Vector between the player's position and the enemy's position `var directionToEnemy = enemy.transform.position - player.transform.position` and then find its projection on the `right` vector of the player's transform, having it > 0 when the enemy is on the right of the player:

```
var directionToEnemy = enemy.transform.position - player.transform.position;
var projectionOnRight = Vector3.Dot(directionToEnemy, player.transform.right);

if (projectionOnRight < 0)
{
    if (waitTime == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("LEFT");
        FireGunsLeft();
    }
}
else if (projectionOnRight > 0)
{
    if (waitTime == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("RIGHT");
        FireGunsRight();
    }
}
```

You also might consider doing the `waitTime == 0` check before you do the calculations for the relative position.

if `Mathf.Approximately(projectionOnRight, 0f)` returns true, then the enemy is right in front of the player and you might want to perform `FireGunsStraight()` or whatever you have for this case.